# Trying to remove something from a list

Tags: python

I am trying to remove something from a list using `listname.remove('thing you want to remove')`. I get an error saying `list.remove(x): x not in list`, but I know it is when I remove `listname.remove` from the code it seems the item I wanted to remove in the list

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def GRS():
  rust_skins_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/itemstore/252490/browse/?filter=Limited'

  TWS = []

  r = requests.get(rust_skins_url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

  images = soup.find_all('img')

  for image in images:
    TWS.append(image['src'])

  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/blank.gif')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/footerLogo_valve_new.png')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/ico/ico_facebook.gif')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/ico/ico_twitter.gif')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/login/throbber.gif')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/header/logo_steam.svg?t=962016')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/header_menu_hamburger.png')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/logo_steam_footer.png')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/header_logo.png')
  TWS.remove('https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/logo_valve_footer.png')

  return TWS

Skins = GRS()

print(Skins)
```

Comment: you need to frame your question better. Code works but what exactly is the problem here? Your wording is a little confusing!

Comment: Show us the *full traceback message* - so that we can tell which of your many `.remove()` calls is the problem.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Works fine here with VSC.

Comment: "it seems the item I wanted to remove in the list"? You didn't finish your sentence.

Comment: Replit is totally irrelevant here, it's only an IDE. The underlying languiage is Python and your issue is with Python.

Comment: Also runs fine here... cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

**The error message is obvious. The element you want to delete is not in this list**

```
TWS = ['https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/shared/images/responsive/logo_valve_footer.png',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/shared/images/responsive/header_menu_hamburger.png',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/shared/images/responsive/header_logo.png',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/shared/images/header/logo_steam.svg?t=962016',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/images/blank.gif',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/images/login/throbber.gif',
       'https://community.akamai.steamstatic.com/economy/image/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835dW4mLBfCk4nReh8DEiv5dbPak9pbw2R_C6iyqIQZk/200fx200f',
       'https://community.akamai.steamstatic.com/economy/image/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835dW4mLHfCk4nReh8DEiv5dYOao4rbMwRPFnozBpIA/200fx200f',
       'https://community.akamai.steamstatic.com/economy/image/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835dW4mLGfCk4nReh8DEiv5daOqo8qrE_R_27f-qS274/200fx200f',
       'https://community.akamai.steamstatic.com/economy/image/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835dW4mLFfCk4nReh8DEiv5dbOKs9q7M3Qfi8Z_CWz2E/200fx200f',
       'https://community.akamai.steamstatic.com/economy/image/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835dW4mLDfCk4nReh8DEiv5dbPqA2rrw-Sf6-Vv4ZXZI/200fx200f',
       'https://community.akamai.steamstatic.com/economy/image/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835dW4mLAfCk4nReh8DEiv5dYOKg_rrc1Rv2-7yifJUc/200fx200f',
       'https://community.akamai.steamstatic.com/economy/image/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835dW4mLEfCk4nReh8DEiv5daOqw7rLc2SPy8kKkqluk/200fx200f',
       'https://community.akamai.steamstatic.com/economy/image/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835dW4mLCfCk4nReh8DEiv5daOq06qb0-Rvy9N_XMdlo/200fx200f',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/images/v6/logo_steam_footer.png',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/images/footerLogo_valve_new.png',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/images/ico/ico_facebook.gif',
       'https://store.st.dl.eccdnx.com/public/images/ico/ico_twitter.gif']

lst = ["https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/blank.gif",
       "https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/footerLogo_valve_new.png",
       "https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/ico/ico_facebook.gif",
       "https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/ico/ico_twitter.gif",
       "https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/login/throbber.gif",
       "https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/header/logo_steam.svg?t=962016",
       'https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/header_menu_hamburger.png',
       'https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/logo_steam_footer.png',
       'https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/header_logo.png',
       "https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/logo_valve_footer.png"
       ]
for i in lst:
    if i in TWS:
        TWS.remove(i)
    else:
        print(f"not in TWS: {i}")
```

out:

```
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/blank.gif
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/footerLogo_valve_new.png
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/ico/ico_facebook.gif
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/ico/ico_twitter.gif
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/login/throbber.gif
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/header/logo_steam.svg?t=962016
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/header_menu_hamburger.png
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/logo_steam_footer.png
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/header_logo.png
not in TWS: https://store.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/public/shared/images/responsive/logo_valve_footer.png
```

Comment: Is that first list what you get when fetching and parsing from the URL? I get URLs matching the ones the asker is trying to remove (and thus I don't get any error). I wonder if the server is serving different versions at different times or to different clients, maybe for load-balancing?

Comment: @CrazyChucky TWS is obtained through URL parsing

Answer (score 1):

There is no link you want to remove. I printed the image["src"]
[image: As you see below]

Comment: If you delete the pictures you want to delete by checking with print, you will not get an error.